# Get path of running assembly from a ClassLibrary Project when the Start Up Project is of type ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble getting the assembly running in a Solution. I have a ClassLibrary Project where I have classes with business rules and I need to pick up a specific assembly to execute C # code at run time. In a ConsoleApplication project, everything works fine, but in a Solution with multiple ClassLibrary projects and a start-up project of the ASP.NET MVC type, this does not work well. Why can not I get the assembly path running in my project of type ClassLibrary when I have a start up project of type ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Post some code please; no idea what you're doing wrong unless we can see what you're trying.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you tell us what type of class library, .NET Framework, Portable, .NET Standard, and what version of framework you are targeting.